# GNU Radio code and data type conversion

Tags: gnuradio, software-development

I am a GNU Radio beginner, and I use the following code to make the block's output-port output a `pmt` data:

```
message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("fer"));
...   
int d_pdu=cnt_int;
pmt::pmt_t pdu = pmt::mp(d_pdu);
message_port_pub(pmt::mp("fer"),pdu);
```

And the "QT GUI Message Edit Box" only can show me that date in type '`int`'. But I can't use it as an integer data. How to change its data type? Is there a block that can make `pmt` into `int`?

Comment: I'm surprised – the QT Gui Message Edit Box should be able to be set to different types, and is set to "String" by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!I've made song changes on the Edit Box module. Let the Edit Box output pdu-type data.
Code:

```
      float d_pda = pmt::to_float(d_msg);     
      pmt::pmt_t pda = pmt::cons(pmt::PMT_NIL, pmt::make_f32vector(8, 
      d_pda));
      message_port_pub(pmt::mp("msg"),pda);
```

Now I can use pdu_to_tagged_stream module to convert msg to float.And the float data can be shown in Number sink module.